# Change logo on hover and scroll with jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have a question about changing logo image with jQuery.

I have this code to change the image with hover:

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('#logo').attr("src", "/logo01.png");

$('#main-header').mouseover(function () {
        $('#logo').attr("src", "/logo01.png");
    })
        .mouseout(function () {
        $('#logo').attr("src", "/logo02.png");
    });
});
```

And i have another code to change image when user scroll:

```
var imageUrl = ['/logo03.png', '/logo01.png',];

    jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var $header = jQuery('header');
        var $logo = jQuery('#logo');

        if ($header.hasClass('et-fixed-header')) {
            return $logo.attr('src', imageUrl[0]);
        };
        return $logo.attr('src', imageUrl[1])
    });
```

When the user scrolls, the et-fixed-header class is added to the header (it's a feature of the theme).

**The problem** is that the first code is applied even when the user scrolls, and therefore when he has the et-fixed-header class.
Instead I want that when the user scrolli is applied only the second code and "ignored" the first one, what can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your logo is inside your header?

If that's the case, use a selector that applies only to the logo inside the header *without* `et-fixed-header` class.

For example, instead of this:

```
$('#logo').attr("src", "/logo01.png");
```

you can use something like this:

```
$('header:not(".et-fixed-header") .logo-image').attr("src", "/logo01.png");
```

As I did above, it's a good idea to use a class instead of an id for the logo.

Comment: Perfect thanks, it works perfectly. I only made one small change: $ ('header: not (". et-fixed-header") #logo') I used the id of the logo instead of the class, why you say it's a good idea to use the class?

Comment: Your solution should also work, but it's semantically incorrect, because an ID is supposed to be unique across your DOM and so, it should include only one ID. But `$("some-selector #some-id")` semantically means an ID with a condition attached, which is against the purpose of using an ID. So, it's generally advised to only have the ID in the selector like this: `$("#some-id")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `mouseover` event to be handled **after** the user scrolls, you can unbind the handler when handing the scroll event:

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('#main-header').unbind('mouseover');
    // ...
```

Hope this helps.